# How can I record the sound from multible sources with gtk-recordMyDesktop?

Tags: audio

I am having problems with sound when I am trying to capture a video.
It captures my sound from my mic, but it dosent record the game sounds, skype sounds, vlc sounds, firefox sounds and everything else aswell.

Im running Fedora 20 LXDE, with pulseaudio installed(and used? maybe?).
And I dont want to change out pulseaudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Record My Desktop* supports **Jack**. Install jack, and then route all those program's output you need to capture to the recorder app. Use `qjackctl` for doing that.

You dont need to remove pulse audio for Jack to work. It can coexist. Some plugins might need to be installed to properly sink and source pulseaudio clients.

Comment: Okay. I installed qjackclt. Is there anything else i have to do inorder for it to work? And how to route all other program's output to jack?

Comment: First, start jack. Then, click "connect" from qjackctl's main window. There you will see writable and readable clients. If you have the required applications running, it show up in readable clients. The recording application will show up in writable clients. Select them together and click connect. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToQjackCtlConnections

Comment: If I start qjactctl, then sound from everything else is gone. Until i restart my computer. Also as i press start, it could not start it.

Comment: I got it to start, but it dosent play any sound. From VLC, or any of my games and skype.

Comment: In ubuntu, there is a package called `pulseaudio-module-jack`. THere should be something similar in fedora too. Install that, and check if you see some pulse audio "sources" and/or "sinks". Use your conscience to connect them accordingly.